# Firebase Web unlink password success but the email still exist in console

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I have some function to Unlink a Password Provider from a user using this code :

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 


user.providerData.forEach(function(providerData) {
 console.log(providerData.providerId);

    if (providerData.providerId == "password") {
        user.unlink("password").then(function() {
           alert("success");
        }).catch(function(error) {
          alert(error);
        });
    }

});
```

The above code is successful without any problem, i can't log in with the email that already unlinked which is great.
But when I check in my console, the email still exists and I can't create a new user with the same name and got the error User already exists.

Is this a Bug ? or is there anything that I miss?

I can unlink user data in Android just fine and the user that unlinked will be deleted too, but not on the web.

EDIT :

I'm using this code to link the Password to the current user, maybe this will help

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(vartxtEmail, vartxtPassword);

user.linkWithCredential(credential)
.then(function(usercred) {
    alert("success");

}).catch(function(error) {
  alert(error);
});
```

Comment: `unlink` only removes the password but the email is kept on the user.

Comment: in the java android, it also remove the email too, is there any workaround for web SDK sir ?

Comment: I highly doubt that. All SDKs use the same [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-unlink-provider) for unlinking.

Comment: @bojeil no, it's true and I already implement it in my Android Application using exactly code in Android Firebase documentation. you can try that if you want

Comment: Did you found any solution to this issue @hakimhomecent

Comment: @RaviParmar not really a solution, but I found a workaround using Admin SDK with NodeJs. so if I want to update the email, phone or even remove it. I just access it using the REST API from Admin SDK at my NodeJs Server. You find more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin